# Changing interface orientation from portrait to landscape causes crash

Tags: ios, unrecognized-selector, nsnull

I have created a universal app that is landscape only using Xcode 7.2 (Landscape left, Landscape right and Require full screen is checked). When I run the application on the iPad simulator, it is showing portrait only. When I tried to change the orientation to landscape it crashes.

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x101c2daf0'"

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash like this.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's tough to tell exactly. My guess is somewhere you are trying to get the length of what you think is an `NSString` but it's actually `NSNull`. From my experience, this would be most likely to occur in some sort of network parsing.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer since the OP doesn't provide any relevant details to say for sure. Obviously the exception indicates that an `NSNull` is being used where an `NSString` is expected. But that doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Actually there is not code that application should crash.Before running application if simulator orientation is landscape.it is working fine.but when i Quit simulator and then start it again.then it is portrait only.When i am trying to change orientation to landscape then it is crashing.Even when press only command it is crashing.